# How to solve: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Which Institute has most number of Students?

```sql
SELECT INSTITUTE 
FROM STUDIES
HAVING COUNT(INSTITUTE) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(INSTITUTE)) 
                           FROM STUDIES 
                           GROUP BY INSTITUTE)
```

What mistake am I making? This seems simple but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: this does not make sense, your top-level query has a HAVING clause which is only valid with a GROUP BY.  It would be best if you showed all the table ddl, sample data, expected output, and explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What DBMS is this?  It matters because there are differences in what non-standard syntaxes are allowed.

Comment: It's SQL Server, based on the error message, I added tags for it. Or maybe could also be Sybase.

Comment: @OldProgrammer TABLE CONSIST OF PROGRAMMER_NAME,COURSE,INSTITUTE,FEES. I WANT NAME OF INSTITUTE HAVING MAX NUMBER OF STUDENTS AND NUMBER OF STUDENTS IN THAT INSTITUTE

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results.

Comment: `What mistake am I making?` Your first mistake is not to read SQL Server documentation for a proper syntax.  You can't write whatever you want to write, and expect SQL Server to somehow understand what you want.  We definitely can't figure out what you are trying to do.  Please do explain.

Answer (score 4):

You can't nest aggregates, like `MAX(COUNT(...))`, that's what the error is saying. If you just need the institute with the most occurrences, there's a much simpler way to do that:

(Judging by the error wording it's Microsoft SQL Server, so that's the syntax I'm using here)

```
SELECT TOP 1 institute 
  FROM studies
 GROUP BY institute
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You just order by the count of occurrences and select the top 1 in that order. There's a caveat here - what if multiple institutes can share the same count and you want all of them? That's where `HAVING` is indeed necessary, and we can use a variant of the above query to get the max:

```
SELECT institute 
  FROM studies
 GROUP BY institute
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) 
                     FROM studies
                    GROUP BY institute
                    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/peSMB10T).

Comment: `TOP (1) WITH TIES` is much simpler for the second version

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY INSTITUTE) AS I_Count
  FROM studies
) X
ORDER BY X.I_Count DESC
```

If you want you can use limit or top 1 to get just one row.

Comment: it will not, still nesting aggregates

Comment: @MarcinJ -- ok I removed that wrong part